# First-chance exception at 0x008437c7 in some.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

*Hi, guys*. I'm kinda stuck on this for some time. I already looked for the solution on other topics, but none fixed.

Here's the error message:

```
First-chance exception at 0x008437c7 in some.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
Unhandled exception at 0x008437c7 in some.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
The program '[2452] some.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Well, what I'm trying to do is to take a program in C and try to put it in C++, for later upgrades. The block that is causing the problem is this (at least, it's where the exception is being fired):

```
int i, j, u, q, count = 0;
int elp[1026][1024], d[1026], l[1026], u_lu[1026], s[1025];
int root[200], loc[200], err[1024], reg[201];
```

What I basically tried to do to fix was to increase the *Stack Reserve Size* and the *Stack Commit Size*, with no success. Give me some hint, please.

Comment: It just *might* have something to do with the fact that you're stack-allocating 1056357 `int` values, i.e  4225428-bytes on a 32bit `int` platform. The real killer is `elp`, btw. You can "fix" it by moving that monster off the stack. Either make it global, static, or dynamic-allocated. The choice is yours.

Comment: Project + Properties, Linker, System.  Set the Stack Reserve Size to 8388608, give or take.

Comment: @HansPassant I already tried it, but this didn't work.

Comment: Well, that should certainly work.  Time to write sane C++ code and use the *new* operator or use the vector class.

Comment: As I already explained, this isn't my code. I'm trying to adapt it from C and check if it does what I need it to do. The "sanity" comes later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to allocate something around 4 MB of data on the stack. In general, you shouldn't be doing this.

The best solution to this problem is to change the code so that each of these arrays (or, particulally, `elp`) is allocated on the heap, instead of the stack. You can either use `new int[]` or, preferably, `std::vector<int>`. If you can't do this, you may try increasing the stack size to a larger value.

Comment: That's not "the best" solution. It is just one of the possible solutions. In code that is called often, using dynamically-allocated memory (local std::vector) can cause a bottleneck. So, depending on sitaution, it might make sense to make container global or static.

Comment: With the context given (these variables having local scope), making them static or global is not functionally equivalent to the original code and outright dangerous at worst.

Comment: Right now, I'm not worried about the performance, I just want to check if the code does what I need. I'll try to use the `vector<int>`. Thanks.